# what's the different between these two statement

Tags: c++, pointers

let say i have these:

```
struct element
{
char buffer[100];
int key;
};
```

then I have this function:

```
int findNext(element* searchValue)
{
    element* current;
    //some code here
    *current=*searchValue;//statement a
    current=searchValue;//statement b
    //some code here
}
```

I just wonder what's the different between statement a and b? Thank you

Comment: First one performs default member-wise copy of one struct to the other; second one just assigns pointer value from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement overwrites the data stored in the `element` pointed to by `current` with the content of what's stored at `searchValue` pointer. Since `current` has not been initialized, that's undefined behavior.

The second statement points `current` to the same `element` as is pointed by the `searchValue`. This is allowed even when `current` has not been initialized.

Here is a diagram illustrating the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In statement a, you are copying the values. I.e value at address pointed by searchValue is  copied to location pointed by current.

In statement b, you are copying the address which is the content of searchValue to current.

Answer (score 0):

```
*current=*searchValue
```

This statement dereferences the pointer `searchValue` and assign it to variable pointed by `current`. Basically the value of `current` is untouched (the address stored remains the same), what changes is data pointed by `current`.

```
current=searchValue
```

Here you work just with pointers (addresses), not with the data they point to. You just set `current` value to `searchValue`. After the statement both variables point to the same memory address, indeed `current == searchValue` (which is not true for the first statement).

Answer (score 0):

*current is of the type `element`. `current` is a pointer to element.
In your code statement a

```
*current=*searchValue;//statement a
```

Assigns the value stored in the aaddress pointed by `searchValue` in the address location pointed by `current`.

statement b

```
current=searchValue;//statement b
```

Makes the address pointed by `current` equal to address pointed by `searchValue` ( address of `element` type)